# change image on orientation change does not work in android 4.0.4 but works in 4.1.3

Tags: android

The manifest file

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
       />
    <activity
                android:name=".landing_screen"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
                android:theme="@style/AppThemes"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

The activity code:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


         if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.home_welcome2);
            } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.home_welcome);
            }

    };
```

It goes in the landscape and portrait block properly but the image does not changes. It works well android 4.1.3 but does not work in 4.0.4.

Any ideas please.

Thanks,

Comment: The culprit line:  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize". Though I might be wrong.

Comment: i tried that but no luck. But I think that is important.

Comment: @asifa can you log something in if and else see in logcat

Comment: Try some trial and error, remove that line from the Manifest and check.

Comment: @Raghunandan i did that it is going in the if and else block properly it is just that the image does not change in 4.0.4 but the image changes in 4.1.3

Comment: I tried that @AstralProjection but it does not work

Comment: What are you testing on? An emulator or a real device?

Comment: I am testing on real device @AstralProjection

Answer (score 0):

change in manifest

```
<activity
                android:name=".landing_screen"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                android:theme="@style/AppThemes"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

Comment: @asifa what is your  target sdk